# image regions corrupt after applying squared filter

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I have this image:

[image: Original image]

I am applying a low-pass square filter to that:

```py
def SquareFilter(imgShape,size):
    filterSquare = np.zeros(imgShape)
    filterSquare[
        imgShape[0]//2-size//2 : imgShape[0]//2+size//2,
        imgShape[1]//2-size//2 : imgShape[1]//2+size//2
    ] = 1
    return filterSquare

im = cv2.imread("Images/wall.jpg",0)

freq = np.fft.fft2(im)
freq2 = np.fft.fftshift(freq)
filtered_g = freq2 * SqFilt
asd = np.fft.ifftshift(np.fft.ifft2(filtered_g))

fel = cv2.normalize(abs(asd), None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)

cv2.imwrite('Results/result.png',fel)
```

but the result is completely different, I think image is divides into 4 region. I don't want this.

[image: Result]

Comment: you did the `ifftshift` _after_ the `ifft`... ishift it _before_ `ifft`. move those things into different expressions. then you see the order clearly.

Comment: For completeness, could you briefly describe the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you take the discrete fourier transform of an image using the FFT, you assume that it lies on an infinite plane of such images repeating at the boundaries. Your filter is not only a low-pass filter, it is also a shift filter. To fix your code, take the ifftshift before the ifft2:

```py
asd = np.fft.ifft2(np.fft.ifftshift(filtered_g))
```

Comment: And Can I use (1-SqFilt) for highpass filter?

Comment: Try it out! In general, it's more intuitive to use something like `scipy.signal.fftconvolve` which takes care of the fun frequency domain stuff for you (unless you have a filter which you want to use in the frequency domain, like an ideal lowpass / ideal highpass filter which usually generate sub par results due to ringing: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ringing_artifacts).